# Form as HMVC widget

Tags: php, forms, widget, hmvc, fuelphp

Is this the right way to create a form widget in FuelPHP?

```
class Controller_Widget extends Controller
{
    public function action_show()
    {
        if (Request::is_hmvc())
        {
            // show form widget
        }
        else
        {
            // process form
        }
    }
}
```

The form action calls the same function to process, but where will it redirect to after? how will it show validation errors?

Note: The widget should not be accessible through the URL; the form should not display itself if accessed directly through the URL.

EDIT:
Found a similar problem in CodeIgniter [HMVC and dynamic widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602061/hmvc-and-dynamic-widgets) but this is from 3 years ago. Maybe the FuelPHP guys have found a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a weird method, a method that is called show but handles both showing and manipulating data? A method called "show" (or get, fetch, read, etc) shouldn't do any editing, it's name expressly seems to imply that it's a read-only operation.

But also how it proceeds seems off. Its read-operation is HMVC only but its manipulation operation is non-HMVC only? That's really a wrong way to determine what the method should do, whether or not it is HMVC should have no baring on what it does.

In your case I'd split this up into 2 methods: one for retrieval (`show()`) and another for manipulation (`edit()` for example). Whether you want to make these HMVC only is up to you. There's more ways than one to solve that, I'd go with:

`if ( ! Request::is_hmvc())
{
    throw new Exception('Only HMVC access allowed.');
}`

Or make it impossible to route to the method by rerouting it in your routes.php config file and then using the HMVC routing overwrite as discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9957367/727225

Comment: I'm thinking of it as some kind of a login / guestbook widget. It's just part of the page/view; the view requests it. I don't have a problem showing the form widget, the problem is when I submit it. I assume it shouldn't be HMVC if I want the form to be submitted.